# CSS height 100% behaves different when embedded in iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/570qvk2p/1/

I have a third-party html document that I am embedding in an iframe.
Within this document there is an element with a css rule specifying height: 100%; A parent some steps up the tree has a fixed height.

When rendering the third party HTMLDocument in its original form, the element with 100% height assumes a size of 18px (fitting to content). When rendering inside an iframe, the element assumes the size of the fixed height parent (200px).

Why would sizing work differently within the iframe and how can I counteract that?

The following is the html that you can see from the fiddle ends up styled different when inserted into an iframe vs when inserted into the top level document:

```
<div style="height: 200px;">
  <ul style="display:block;">
    <li>
      <div style="height: 100%;">1</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div style="height: 100%;">2</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div style="height: 100%;">3</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This question:
[Element in iframe with height: 100% strech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32154459/element-in-iframe-with-height-100-strech) 
describes the same phenomenon, but that particular case is solvable for me by setting a size on the html tag before deferring to the iframe size. What I am showing above seems to be a more general case of the same issue described by that person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your iframe has no `doctype` which seems to be causing the rendering issues.

Constructing your iframe with a defined doctype gives consistent rendering between your page and iframe:

```
var doc = window.frames[0].document;

var a = doc.createElement("div");
var b = document.createElement("div");
var content = "<div style=\"height: 200px;\"><ul style=\"display:block;\"><li><div style=\"height: 100%;\">1</div></li><li><div style=\"height: 100%;\">2</div></li><li><div style=\"height: 100%;\">3</div></li></ul></div>";

doc.open();
doc.write("<!DOCTYPE html>");
doc.write("<html>");
doc.write("<head></head>");
doc.write("<body>" + content + "</body>");
doc.write("</html>");
doc.close();

b.innerHTML = content;
document.body.appendChild(b);
```

[Updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/570qvk2p/2/)

I was under the impression that an iframe inherited the doctype of the parent page but this doesn't seem to be the case. Perhaps somebody else can elaborate?

Comment: You appear to be correct in terms of the example I offered, which is great! It has lead me in the right direction. However on the real DOM I am working with, there is a doctype <!DOCTYPE html> which is created with document.implementation.createDocumentType and is clearly successfully appended to the document. However document.doctype remains null. Any ideas on why that may be?

Comment: No idea to be honest. Hopefully somebody else will come along who can help you out. Good luck!

Comment: `let newtype = document.implementation.createDocumentType('html', '', '');
   window.iframe.document.insertBefore(newtype, window.iframe.document.documentElement);`

Comment: I've not got the `createDocumentType` to actually work though. Something wrong with the references. `.write()` works though.